# jQuery: How to create a 360 view form photos

Tags: jquery, html, 360-degrees, 360-panorama, virtual-tour

I am trying to create a 360/3D view of a product(s).

To accomplish this, I started by using 3dEye. With this jQuery plug-in, all I have to do is dump regular photos into a folder. Ej, `photos/cup-1/`, `photos/cup-2/` and `photos/car/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>3D Products</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="3deye.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cup-1").vc3dEye({
        imagePath: "photos/cup-1/",
        totalImages: 7,
        imageExtension: "jpg"
        });

        $("#cup-2").vc3dEye({
        imagePath: "photos/cup-2/",
        totalImages: 13,
        imageExtension: "jpg"
        });

        $("#car").vc3dEye({
        imagePath: "photos/car/",
        totalImages: 51,
        imageExtension: "png"
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample of 360-view products</h1>
    <h2>Move the object with the mouse</h2>

    <br /><br />
    <div id="cup-1"></div>
    <div id="cup-2"></div>
    <div id="car"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Live sample:** http://stackoverflow.juvera.co/360-view/

However, 3dEye has a lot of drawbacks.

- I can only have one object on the same page. If I add more pages, it covers the other objects with a green overlay and the loading label remains.
- It has no zoom option
- No controls for movement (like autoplay, move left button, move right button)
- etc.

### Do you know of a really good jQuery plugin (or other solution) I could use to accomplish this?

It has to be mobile friendly and allow screen swiping (with the finger)

PS. It would be great if I could use the same solution for panorama and virtual tours...but if not is OK

Comment: I've found https://github.com/creativeaura/threesixty-slider  to be good for mobile and desktop use. Its responsive, has autoplay, and controls as you require. The only thing missing is zoom, but you can use js to scale the image yourself.